# How to make warnings appear next to code in Android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, warnings

Yesterday, when I had an error or warning  a little icon would appear next to my code.  Warnings would be have a little orange icon and errors would have a little red icon.  Now that feature has suddenly stopped.

What can I do to get these icons back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `Windows` then `Preferences` then click on `Java` on the left, then `Editor` and check the box that says `Report problems as you type`

Comment: Thankyou.  The box was allready ticked on so I unticked it and restarted Eclipse.  Then I ticked it and restarted Eclipse again.  For some reason this created unexplained errors in my other "values" folders (the alternate language folders).  I deleted these and pasted them in again.  Now all works as it used to!